# jQuery Cycle2 possible change use multi-transitions

Tags: jquery, transition, cycle

I'm trying to recreate this effect in cycle2.
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/multi.html

The slideshow needs to alternate from fx:'scrollHorz' to fx:'scrollvert', however it seems that you cannot change the transition effect in cycle 2?

Could anyone help?
Thanks.

I've tried using this;

```
jQuery( '.slideshow' ).on('cycle-before', function(e, slideOpts, soutgoingSlideEl,          incomingSlideEl) { var active = jQuery(incomingSlideEl) if (active.is('.slide2')) {    slideOpts.fx = 'fade'; } });
```

Comment: Please post examples of what you have tried so far!

Comment: In the question itself please!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Caveat, I am not as well versed in jQuery as I would like. If anyone can see a way to simplify this code please feel free to do so.

I created a plugin that is similar to what you are asking. Instead of being able to direct each individual slide you use fx:random

This will make the slide randomly move either up, down, left, or right.

```
!function(a){
    "use strict";
    a.fn.cycle.transitions.random={
        before: function( opts, curr, next, fwd ) {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            console.log(rand);
            if (rand === 0){
                // Scroll Up
                    opts.API.stackSlides( opts, curr, next, fwd );
                    var height = opts.container.css('overflow','hidden').height();
                    opts.cssBefore = { top: fwd ? height : -height, left: 0, opacity: 1, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible' };
                    opts.animIn = { top: 0 };
                    opts.animOut = { top: fwd ? -height : height };
            }else if (rand === 1){
                    var flag=true;
                    if(flag===true){
                        fwd = !fwd;
                        flag=false;
                    }
                // Scroll Down
                    opts.API.stackSlides( opts, curr, next, fwd );
                    var height = opts.container.css('overflow','hidden').height();
                    opts.cssBefore = { top: fwd ? height : -height, left: 0, opacity: 1, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible' };
                    opts.animIn = { top: 0 };
                    opts.animOut = { top: fwd ? -height : height };
                    if(flag===false){
                        fwd = fwd;
                        flag=true;
                    }
            }else if ( rand === 2 ){
                // Scroll Right
                    var flag=true;
                    if(flag===true){
                        fwd = !fwd;
                        flag=false;
                    }
                    opts.API.stackSlides( curr, next, fwd );
                    var w = opts.container.css('overflow','hidden').width();
                    opts.cssBefore = { left: fwd ? w : - w, top: 0, opacity: 1, visibility: 'visible', display: 'block' };
                    opts.cssAfter = { zIndex: opts._maxZ - 2, left: 0 };
                    opts.animIn = { left: 0 };
                    opts.animOut = { left: fwd ? -w : w };
                    if(flag===false){
                        fwd = fwd;
                        flag=true;
                    }
            }else if( rand === 3 ){
                // Scroll Left
                    opts.API.stackSlides( curr, next, fwd );
                    var w = opts.container.css('overflow','hidden').width();
                    opts.cssBefore = { left: fwd ? w : - w, top: 0, opacity: 1, visibility: 'visible', display: 'block' };
                    opts.cssAfter = { zIndex: opts._maxZ - 2, left: 0 };
                    opts.animIn = { left: 0 };
                    opts.animOut = { left: fwd ? -w : w };
            }
        }
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this :

```
jQuery('.slideshow'.on('cycle-before', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
  var trans = ['fade','tileSlide','tileBlind'];            // list of possible transitions
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(trans.length+1));   // choose a random transition
  var opts = jQuery(incomingSlideEl).data('cycle.opts');   // get the incoming slide options
  opts.fx = trans[rand];                                   // change the fx option
  jQuery(incomingSlideEl).data('cycle.opts', opts);        // replace the incoming slide options with updated ones
});
```